# Better way to test non null fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have an object that contain some fields, I want to check if some fields are not null and not empty. Is there an good way to do that in java 8 or apache utilities...

I don't want do something like

```
if(myObj.getMyField1 != null || myObj.getMyField1 != "" || myObj.getMyField2 != null || myObj.getMyField2 != "" || myObj.getMyField3 != null || myObj.getMyField3 != "") {}
```

this is myObj

```
@Data // lombok for generating getters and setters
public class Myobj {
   private String myField1;
   private String myField2;
   private String myField3;
   private String myField4;
   private String myField5;

   private AnotherObj myField6;

}
```

Would you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Is `getMyField1` supposed to be a getter (actually `getMyField1()`) or a field access (actually `myField1`)?

Comment: @Holger by looking at the code of myObj, it would need to be getter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using java-8 [Stream#anyMatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to checking the strings is whether `null` or empty. for example:

```
boolean hasNullOrEmptyString = Stream.of(myField1,myField2,...,myFieldN)
                                     .anyMatch(it-> it==null || it.isEmpty());
```

**OR** you can replace lambda expression with method reference expression which the method can be reused later:

```
boolean hasNullOrEmptyString = Stream.of(myField1,myField2,...,myFieldN)
                                     .anyMatch(this::isNullOrEmptyString);

boolean isNullOrEmptyString(String it){
  return it==null || it.isEmpty();
}
```

**OR** as I see your question that marked as spring, and spring already has a utility method `StringUtils#isEmpty` for check a `String` whether is `null` or empty:

```
boolean hasNullOrEmptyString = Stream.of(myField1,myField2,...,myFieldN)
                                     .anyMatch(StringUtils::isEmpty);
```

Comment: Thanks @holi-java But when a fields is null the application throw **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Comment: @Victor Hi, you can see this [How to fix NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/24100776#24100776) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @holi-java. Concerning NullpointerException i check if the object is null and then applying **Stream.of...** in each fields of that object

Comment: @Victor Not at all. I only could give you some suggestion since you didn't put your example code in question.

Comment: This the first verification:   `boolean addressValidation = (cInfo.getAddress() != null)? Stream.of(cInfo.getAddress().getZip(), cInfo.getAddress().getCity()).anyMatch(StringUtils::isEmpty): false;`

Comment: This the second one `boolean proValidation = addressValidation && Stream.of(cInfo.getCompanyName(), cInfo.getCountry(), cInfo.getLegalForm()).anyMatch(StringUtils::isEmpty);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Apache StringUtils class : 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAnyEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence...-

Comment: Thanks @milcaepsilon, you link is only for strings.

Comment: @Victor I assume you want to test strings since you use `!= ""`

Comment: I want a way to test without coding a lot, for example make the name of fields in an ArrayList and make a loop to check every field in that is present in the list

Comment: Do you want to test only String fields or any type of properties ? (Cf your `AnotherObj` )

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this as spring-boot, so I'm assuming you might be using controllers and validating their parameters. If that is the case, just do

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Data
public class Myobj {
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1)
   private String myField1;
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1)
   private String myField2;
   /* etc */
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url", method = POST)
public void yourMethod(@RequestBody @Valid YourObject yourObject) {
    // 
}
```

Then your object will be validated on instantiation.

Comment: Thanks @eis how I can catch "@NotNull" if there is an notNullException in my code

Comment: @Victor via an [exception handler or controller advice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).